# Django is giving different date values for objects accessed via queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, utc

Context I get different values for datetime field when I access them differently. I am sure there is some utc edge magic going on here.

```
(Pdb++) 
Foo.objects.all().values_list('gated_out__occurred__date')[0][0]
datetime.date(2021, 9, 9)
(Pdb++) Foo.objects.all()[0].gated_out.occurred.date()
datetime.date(2021, 9, 10)
```

Edit: They have the same PK

```
Foo.objects.all().order_by("pk")[0].gated_out.occurred.date()
datetime.date(2021, 9, 10)
(Pdb++) Foo.objects.all().order_by("pk").values_list('gated_out__occurred__date')[0][0]
datetime.date(2021, 9, 9)
```

How do I fix/figure out what is happening?

Comment: Have you checked the primary key of both those records, just to be sure they're the same?

Comment: @JohnGordon looks like it. I have ordered them by "pk"